# Execution Timeout Expired when paging for Entity Framework Core 5

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core

**1. My problem:**

I am currently using Entity Framework Core 5.

I querying page 1 is OK (under 2s), but for page 2, I wait a long time and throw exception

I check the log and it says:

> "Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to
> completion of the operation or the server is not responding."

Sometimes it works, I also suspect it's server issue but not sure.

**2. What I've tried:**

I tried to test by generating SQL code and execute on SQL Server. It's working.

**3. This is my code:**

```
var query = context.A
.Include(x => x.User).ThenInclude(x => x.UserMembership)
.Include(x => x.Company)
.Where(obj =>
(request.DateFrom == DateTime.MinValue 
 || obj.TransactionDate.Value.Date >= request.DateFrom.Date) 
 && (request.DateTo == DateTime.MinValue 
 || obj.TransactionDate.Value.Date < request.DateTo.AddDays(1).Date)
)
.OrderByDescending(x => x.DT)
.Select(obj => new GridModel()
                    {
                        Id = obj.Id,
                        CreatedBy = bj.User.UserMembership.Email,
                        CompanyName = obj.Company.Name,
                    });

var list = await query.Skip((filter.PageNumber - 1) * filter.PageSize).Take(filter.PageSize).ToListAsync();
```

Anyone who has encountered this case, please support me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Move the functions out of the query for starters, you can conditionally build the query that will remove ambiguity from it.

Comment: There's no need for the catch-all conditions. You can easily build the query with eg `if(paramDate !=null) { query=query.Where(....);}`

Comment: Yes. I understand. But it's not solution for this issue

Comment: How often that encountered? Always or sometimes? Did you tried to set `this.context.CommandTimeout` inside your dbContext so far?

Comment: Sometimes. I've await too long 30 seconds but still throw ex